# Is this site about public aviation or also meant for private pilots?

Tags: discussion

It is not clear to me what the focus of this site is.
For example here in Germany it is a major pain to deal with all the licensing stuff if you are a private pilot. Would questions about these topics be on topic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say this is by and for people who are interested in aviation. I'm pretty sure you'll find more private pilots than people with lot's of frequent flyer miles though, but that's just my guess.

In my personal opinion, licensing is a big part of it, so as far as I'm concerned, go for it.

Answer (score 5):

I would say the site encompasses both aspects, but as roe said will definitely attract a lot of private pilots so your topic idea is a great one!